# Qt connect mainwindow and dialog using signal and slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am trying to connect `mainwindow` and dialog using signal and slot. I am very new to qt. I have a `lineEdit` and a `pushButton` in `mainwindow.ui`, a `lineEdit` in `dialog.ui`. And I have those very basic code:
mainwindow.h:

```
signals:
    void sendString(QString);
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog *mDialog = new Dialog(this);
    emit sendString(ui->lineEdit->text());
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendString(QString)), mDialog, SLOT(showString(QString)));
    mDialog->show();
}
```

dialog.h:

```
private slots:
    void showString(QString);
```

dialog.cpp:

```
void Dialog::showString(QString str)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(str);
}
```

But after I clicked the `pushButton`, the dialog showed, but nothing changed in the `lineEdit`.
I hope I explain this clearly enough?
Can someone explain to me why and how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: emit signal after connect clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emit signal after connect

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dialog *mDialog = new Dialog(this);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendString(QString)), mDialog, SLOT(showString(QString)));
    mDialog->show();

    emit sendString(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the connection **before** the emit.

But in your case you dont need the signal of the of the mainwindow at all. You invoke the showString method directly.